# How can I extract the running scripts name using PCOMM VBScript

Tags: vbscript

First time posting so please forgive me if I miss something.

I'm trying to output the name of the running script (along with other variables) to a plain text file. I've been able to get everything else I need except for the Script Name. I've tried using WScript & Echo commands but they do not appear to function in my environment. These are PCOMM .mac files.

Thanks in advance

Here are some of things I've tried so far:

```
FilePath = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".")`
```

<<< The above works for Filepath but does not include the macro name

`FileName = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFileName(".")`
<<< The above just outputs the "."

```
Dim scriptName : scriptName = WScript.ScriptName
```

<<< The above gives error message: Variable is undefined: 'WScript'

```
Dim scriptName : WScript.Echo WScript.ScriptName
```

<<< The above gives error message: Variable is undefined: 'WScript'

```
Function GetName() 
Dim WshShell, objEnv

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objEnv = WshShell.Environment("Process")
GetName = objEnv("SCRIPTNAME")

End Function
```

<<< The above doesn't output anything. I used similar logic to successfully extract the HOMEPATH.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this one out after all:

```
REM Initialize the session
   sHandle = autECLConnMgr.autECLConnList(1).Handle

REM Connect to the current session
   sHandle = autECLSession.Handle

   msgbox("Variable Check: " & ThisMacroName), vbOKOnly, "Validation check"
```